# Pagination is not Working with custom method in SpringBoot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

When I was fetching the data only it was working properly, but now I want to apply pagination its not working don't know why? I have tried running query in mysql and there it is working but here not working. Any help can be appreciated, thanks.

My User Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

Address Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "pincode")
    private String pincode;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private User user;

    //... getters and setters
}
```

My repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

@Query(value="select * from user inner join address on address.id=user.id where city=?2",nativeQuery=true)
public List<User> findUsersFromCity(Pageable pageable,String city)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try JPQL query for pagination  like this:

```
@Query(“select * from User u join u.address a where a.city= :city ”)
public Page<User> findUsersFromCity(Pageable pageable,@Param("city")String city)
```

Comment: why its not working before, can you tell what was the mistake?

Comment: You were using List<> instead of Page<>. Pageable's return type is Page not List.

Answer (score 3):

Native count queries should be declared for pagination at the query method when native SQL is used, according to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.native).

Consider declaring [query method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details) as shown below, which doesn't require writing JPQL or native SQL.

```
public Page<User> findAllByAddress_City(Pageable pageable, String city);
```

Comment: why its not working before, can you tell what was the mistake?

Comment: I've updated the answer, hope it's clearer now.